# openright reseting

Tags: margins

I have a rather larger document, where I use "openright":

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
```

I then have a few of my pages in the middle of the document where I use:

```
\newgeometry{left=10mm,right=10mm,bottom=25mm}
    %stuff
\restoregeometry
```

because i need more space.

The problem is that after the pages with the newgeometry, the "openright" gives me larger margins on the wrong side of the page. Is there a simple way to fix this?

I tried adding a /newpage and /cleardoublepage before restoring the geometry, but is doesn't change anything. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.